# How to detect a property return type in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, runtime, properties, types, key-value-observing

I have an object in objective-c at runtime, from which I only know the KVC key and I need to detect the return value type (e.g. I need to know if its an NSArray or NSMutableArray) of this property, how can I do that?

Comment: Where does the information in your XML file come from? Would it be possible to add an entry to indicate the type of each property?

Comment: The xml file is also out of my control. I'm creating an xml serializer which converts an xml file in an object structure. Of course, the objects have to be available, but I need sertain information about the object at runtime to fill in the data correctly.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You're talking about runtime property introspection, which happens to be something that Objective-C is [very good at](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/Articles/ocrtPropertyIntrospection.html).

In the case you describe, I'm assuming you have a class like this:

```
@interface MyClass
{
    NSArray * stuff;
}
@property (retain) NSArray * stuff;
@end
```

Which gets encoded in XML something like this:

```
<class>
    <name>MyClass</name>
    <key>stuff</key>
</class>
```

From this information, you want to recreate the class and also give it an appropriate value for `stuff`.

Here's how it might look:

```
#import <objc/runtime.h>

// ...

Class objectClass;       // read from XML (equal to MyClass)
NSString * accessorKey;  // read from XML (equals @"stuff")

objc_property_t theProperty =
    class_getProperty(objectClass, accessorKey.UTF8String);

const char * propertyAttrs = property_getAttributes(theProperty);
// at this point, propertyAttrs is equal to: T@"NSArray",&,Vstuff
// thanks to Jason Coco for providing the correct string

// ... code to assign the property based on this information
```

Apple's documentation (linked above) has all of the dirty details about what you can expect to see in `propertyAttrs`.

Comment: Actually, it would be equal to T@"NSArray",&,Vstuff ;-)

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be the best way, I'm going to try it.

Btw. your example is quite near to what I'm doing, but it can be any xml file, so my key is the element name.

Comment: How can I produce this @"NSArray" type string with @encode()? I tried @enocde(NSArray *) an dit did not work.

Comment: I'm not sure if you can do that with @encode. Your best bet is to ask another question here on SO :)

Comment: That would be the next step ;)

Comment: I take issue with the assessment that Objective-C is "very good at" property introspection. A good implementation would more closely resemble 'propArray = [object properties]' and return an array of property objects, each with metadata describing the property in detail. Instead, our property is a mysterious 'objc_property_t'. To get it, you have to take your prop name and pull the UTF8 version of it. The resultant descriptor is an arcane string, which I have to parse myself? Yes, Objective-C lets you introspect properties, but there is nothing about its implementation I would consider good.

Comment: No, not sour grapes.   Objective-C is quite explicitly *not* designed with the intention of supporting this kind of formal, at runtime, dynamic behaviors based upon type introspection, be it properties or other runtime introspection mechanisms.  As Greg says, the support for such is not good though for a different reason than he states;  it isn't good because such support was specifically *not a consideration when designing the language or runtime*.

Comment: @GregMaletic - You can use `property_copyAttributeList()` instead to get an array of key/value pairs.

Comment: Is there a way to find out what type of objects are in `NSArray`?

Answer (score 17):

Cheap answer: use [the NSObject+Properties source here](http://github.com/AlanQuatermain/aqtoolkit/tree/367b73a47e1a459a3758e138024d68dd92c7f33b/Extensions).

It implements the same methodology described above.

Comment: I often like to reinvent the wheel, so I will probably do something like this and use this library as an example/reference. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 4):

The preferred way is to use the methods defined in the [NSObject Protocol](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html).

Specifically, to determine if something is either an instance of a class or of a subclass of that class, you use `-isKindOfClass:`. To determine if something is an instance of a particular class, and only that class (ie: not a subclass), use `-isMemberOfClass:`

So, for your case, you'd want to do something like this:

```
// Using -isKindOfClass since NSMutableArray subclasses should probably
// be handled by the NSMutableArray code, not the NSArray code
if ([anObject isKindOfClass:NSMutableArray.class]) {
    // Stuff for NSMutableArray here
} else if ([anObject isKindOfClass:NSArray.class]) {
    // Stuff for NSArray here

    // If you know for certain that anObject can only be
    // an NSArray or NSMutableArray, you could of course
    // just make this an else statement.
}
```

Comment: In Enyra case 'anObject' is nil. Look comments in my respond.

Comment: This test will not work. All arrays — even immutable ones — are descended from NSMutableArray.

Comment: isMemberOfClass: is the check which ignore inheritance.

Comment: @Chuck I know this is ancient, but I think you have that backwards: `NSMutableArray` descends from `NSArray`, not the other way around: `[mutableArray isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]` is true, whereas `[array isKindOfClass:[NSMutableArray class]]` is not.

Answer (score 2):

This is really a comment addressing an issue raised by Greg Maletic in response to answer provided by e.James 21APR09.

Agreed that Objective-C could use a better implementation for getting these attributes.
Below is a method I quickly threw together to retrieve attributes of a single object property:

```
- (NSArray*) attributesOfProp:(NSString*)propName ofObj:(id)obj{

    objc_property_t prop = class_getProperty(obj.class, propName.UTF8String);
    if (!prop) {
       // doesn't exist for object
       return nil;
    }
    const char * propAttr = property_getAttributes(prop);
    NSString *propString = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:propAttr];
    NSArray *attrArray = [propString componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
    return attrArray;
}
```

Partial list of attribute keys:

- R     Read-only
- C     Copy of last value assigned
- &     Reference to last value assigned
- N     Nonatomic property
- W     Weak reference

Full list at [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/Articles/ocrtPropertyIntrospection.html)

Comment: Note regarding Slipp D. Thompson's edit from the bracket messaging to dot-syntax:  The dot-syntax edit above will actually result in a compiler error for the "obj.class" call in both Xcode 6.4 and the Xcode 7 Beta (you would need to update the "id" declaration to "NSObject" to resolve).  I am proponent of Jon Reid's opinion that using dot-syntax for messaging in ObjC is generally unwise:  http://qualitycoding.org/dot-notation/#comments

Answer (score 1):

You can use isKindOfClass message

```
if([something isKindOfClass:NSArray.class])
     [somethingElse action];
```

Comment: the problem is, the object is newly created, so also the property value is nil. I just have a KVC Key, from which I event don't know if the object really has this accessors, but if it has it, I need to know the type of this return value without having the according object in hand.

Comment: Why not to make your logic decision later when you will have an object? Objective C is more runtime language then static.

Comment: @Enyra: that's okay. Using the above, if the object is nil, it will return false even if it is eventually going to be an array.

Comment: [myObject valueForKey:@"theKnownKey"] is nil for sure, so i can make following:
[[myObject valueForKey:@"theKnownKey"] isKindOf:[NSArray class]] ?

Comment: @Mykola: I'm reading an xml file and filling it into objects of classes I don't know during runtime, when I fill in the property value of the class, I need to check if I can fill in the new value / object directly into the property, or if I have to create an array and fill in the object into the array, so I can not wait until I have an object value :)

Comment: I assume that you want to mutate the array but don't want to throw an exception? Instead, why not use respondsToSelector: to see if your mutation selector is available? If not, do whatever you want. If so, feel free to mutate (call) it.

Comment: I tend to think that without "dummy" object with non-nil value you won't be able to retrieve runtime data type.

Comment: Not only mutate, I create a class by NSClassForString and instantiate it. If I iterate thru the children elements, I check want to check if the according property value type is an array or not. Since I can not control, which classes I create, I also can not assume, that the array instance already has been created and if not, i want to create it myself

Comment: Hmmm... you could use the runtime to get information about a property, but I'm not sure that's really what you'd want either...

Answer (score 0):

If you know that the property is defined :

```
        id vfk = [object valueForKey:propertyName];
        Class vfkClass = vfk.class;
```

And compare with isKindOfClass, isSubClass, etc.

Comment: What if the current value is nil?