# Is there any way to get a property's type in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to detect a property return type in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/769319/how-to-detect-a-property-return-type-in-objective-c)

Is there any way to get a property's type in Objective-C?  I can access the property like this:

```
objc_property_t* properties = class_copyPropertyList(cl, &count);
```

And get the name like this:

```
property_getName(properties[i]);
```

What I need to do though is get the type.  Also, the value will be `nil` in most cases so I can't just get the value calling `object_getClass()`.

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/769319/how-to-detect-a-property-return-type-in-objective-c ; also note that good keywords to find what you're looking for are: objective-c reflection introspection

Comment: Use `property_getAttributes(properties[i])`

Comment: Note also that Objective-C was not designed with the intention to support this level of runtime dynamic behaviors.  You are generally far better off designing a system that captures the dynamism you need in a formal API within your code (and not building on things like @proeprty or @ encode generated metadata).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not in the sense that you seem to be asking — in Objective-C classes are typeless; when dealing with non-C types beyond 'it's a class' the type of properties isn't known at runtime. That's why if you do something silly like the following in a view controller:

```
[self setValue:@3 forKey:@"view"];
```

You'll see an exception raised when the controller attempts to send a view message to the `NSNumber` rather than by the key-value coding mechanisms because you tried to put something that isn't a view into in an inappropriate property.

Parsing `property_getAttributes` will allow you to go no further than distinguishing the various C literal types from an Objective-C object type.