# Objective C Determine is value is appropriate for setting

Tags: objective-c

I have this in code, but I want to determine that not only the object responds to the selector, but the type of the value corresponds with the type of the property.

```
   if ([object respondsToSelector:NSSelectorFromString(propName)]) 
      [object setValue:value forKey:propName];
```

For example, if value is a boolean and the property is a string, I want the if to short circuit.

Comment: There's no easy built in way to do this, but you can determine an @property's type at runtime, then compare that with the type of value. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/769319/how-to-detect-a-property-return-type-in-objective-c

Comment: How general of an approach do you need? For a specific object for a specific property? Or are you trying to implement static typing at run time throughout the language?

Comment: You've got the first half; the type checking is answered by the other question.

Answer (score 2):

You can also accomplish this by overriding your setter.  This way you don't need to check in every different place you are setting the property.

```
- (void) setSomeString:(NSString *)someString {
    if (![someString isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) return;

    _someString = someString;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use this category [NSObject+Properties](https://github.com/AlanQuatermain/aqtoolkit/tree/367b73a47e1a459a3758e138024d68dd92c7f33b/Extensions), The category Extends NSObject adding the possibility to check,among other things, if an object has a property.

```
- (BOOL) hasPropertyNamed: (NSString *) name;
- (BOOL) hasPropertyNamed: (NSString *) name ofType: (const char *) type;
- (BOOL) hasPropertyForKVCKey: (NSString *) key;
```

Comment: Please add some explanation of what this code does, possibly including some relevant snippets, and why you think it would solve the problem. Posts which consist solely of links aren't good SO answers.