# Obtaining class of key at runtime

Tags: cocoa, objective-c-runtime, key-value-coding

I have a class with below interface:

```
@interface MyData : NSObject
@property (readwrite, strong) NSString *urlToParse;
@property (readwrite, strong) MappingElement *titleElement;


- (instancetype)initWithPlist:(NSString *)plistPath;
```

Its implementation is like this:

```
- (instancetype)initWithPlist:(NSString *)plistPath
{
    if (self = [super init]) {
        NSDictionary *plistData = [[NSDictionary alloc]
initWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
        [self setValuesForKeysWithDictionary:plistData];
    }

    return self;
}

#pragma mark KVC related methods
- (void)setValue:(id)value forKey:(NSString *)key
{
    NSLog(@"key class: ",[[self valueForKey:key] class]); // it is printing nil, prints
correct value if key is initialized in init method
}
```

Now there are two scenarios:

**Scenario 1:** Do not initialize instance variables in `initWithPlist:` method

In this case if I try to log class of key in `setValue:forKey:` method,
it prints nil.

**Scenario 2:** Initialize instance variables in `initWithPlist:` method

In this case if I try to log class of key in `setValue:forKey:` method,
it prints `NSString` and then `MappingElement`.

Is there any way to achieve the same result in 'Scenario 1', may be by
using any API from Objective=C runtime?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to detect a property return type in Objective-C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/769319/how-to-detect-a-property-return-type-in-objective-c)

Comment: @JesseRusak thanks for the pointer, it seems similar, hence marking this posted question as resolved.